E-Core Electromagnet Vs. Bar Electromagnet: Force and Range
I have this microwave transformer (model number MD-601AMR-1) that I repurposed into an electromagnet. And it is very strong, but the magnetic field does not reach out far enough for my application. Here is a sketch of the core I'm using (units are cm, core is extruded 6cm):

I know that a bar magnet shape, while weaker, creates fields further out. My question is, if I cut off the two outer legs of the core, how much weaker will the magnet become and how much farther out will the magnetic fields reach? Right now I'm pushing 12 amps through the coil and it's generating at least 40N of force when the load is applied directly to the magnet (my newton meter maxes out at 40N). I only need 1.5N at about 2-3 inches away from the magnet.

I think your real problem is magnetism decreases with the cube of the distance.  Different cores will not let you get around this physical fact.

@evildemonic But the cube of the distance, scaled by what reference dimension? That is the question. The bar magnet would indeed have a longer distance between poles. But less strength for the same magnetization, so it's a reasonable and interesting question.

@evildemonic Only once your source size << distance is it cubed. Before that, it's more square-ish. Really close to it, linear-ish.

I've always answered this question by experiment.  I've played around with answering it with FEMM, but I've never backed up my FEMM explorations with experiment.  Depending on cost, you may want to just whack up a core and try it out -- or find a 2.5mm bar of iron to wind a coil around and try that.

Sure, and I agree that it needs to be tested at the bench, but just rough estimating I'm thinking a ~1 inch core, "2-3 inches away"... my possibly wildly wrong assumption is you are going to be seeing at least 2+ orders of magnitude reduction in force.  And, of course, it is a reasonable and interesting question.

I wonder if a cone-shaped core could help concentrate the flux?

Take a look at your flux path on your magnet when the object is not near.  Your path is shorter than the distance away from the object you want to attract.  There are only two air gaps in your path, and each one is only 1.5 inches.  And the field direction is pretty horizontal, which is not what you need.

When you bring your object you are trying to attract into your field, you are hoping for the flux path shown.  But this flux path has three air gaps, each 2-3 inches away, so the reluctance is far greater than the path shown in the first case.

Not happening.
What you need to do is to make the flux path have a lower reluctance than the path between the center and the legs.  This means that your air gap must be shorter.  The drawing below gives the concept.  The field is in the right direction and the field is more concentrated, and the "T" shaped piece will be more strongly attracted as it slides between the longer legs.  There are other ways to achieve this, but I hope this gives the idea.


I am not able to extend the core to meet the object, the gap is solid wood (the magnet is meant to drag the object from the other side of the wood). Could I achieve a similar result by chopping off part of the middle leg to make the "closed" path harder for the flux to travel through? Therefor encouraging it to travel through the object for an easier path?

You will have to go too big if you want to pull across two-three inches.  Even solenoids that are optimized for flux paths generally have strokes less than an inch.  Can you space nails in the wood that go most of the way through?

I can't put nails in the board. Also my 2-3" estimate was wrong, the wood is only 1.75" thick. I can take an angle grinder to the core and chop off the outer legs to reattach them even further out. Do you think this method of maximizing the reluctance of the path without the target object would work?
